# DevExpress XrChart curve prints to PDF but not on Print-Out

Tags: pdf, printing, charts, devexpress, xtrareport

I have two line charts on a DevExpress xtrareport. For some reason, the curves are drawn fine on one but not the other.

If I print the report using PDF995 application, or using Microsoft XPS document Writer, both charts appear fine. 
However, if I print the report directly to the printer (a TA/UTAX), the curves on one of the graphs don't appear at all. 
This is a screenshot from the output of the XPS document.

[image]

But when it's sent directly to the printer, the curves don't appear on the left hand graph. Below is a scan of the same graphs printed to the printer.

[image]

I'm fairly positive it is related to the data in the data series because if I switch the binding so that the right-hand graph uses the current left-hand data, I get the same problem but with *that* graph. However, on examining the data, I can't find anything amiss.

The data comes from a list of Tuples (`string`, `decimal`, `decimal`):

- The `SeriesDataMember` is bound to `Item1`
- The `ArgumentDataMember` is bound to `Item2`
- The `ValueDataMembers` Value is bound to `Item3`

And the report is printed using the DevExpress `ReportPrintTool.Print()` method.

Strangely, the graph on the left in the screenshot is printed fine, and that gets its data from a similar data structure.

What could be different between printing to an actual printer and printing to a PDF writer? (`PDF995`)

**Edit**

As per my comment, starting the curve at -0.01, -0.01 allows extra space below the origin and then the curve prints fine. This currently works as a workaround as the graph will never be printed in a fine enough detail to notice the difference between 0.01 and 0. But still... weird...

[image]

Comment: Further investigation revealed that the curves seem to not appear when the points get too close to the axes! For example, if I set the first point to be -0.01, -0.01, the graph allows some extra space below zero on both the X axis and Y axis, and now it prints fine!

Answer (score 0):

is that curves visible on the real printer if you try to print result Microsoft XPS document file?
currently i think that your problem is in your printer : (

Comment: Possibly... It seems very specific though... Also, see my comment/edit above, it prints fine if I force it to leave extra space under and to the left of the zeroes.